# Adding a new version number to Stack Overflow Documentation

Tags: feature-request, documentation

When reviewing the Scala topics, I found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/scala/3664/scala-2-12-features#t=201607251410489266454), which documents features in Scala 2.12. Notably, this is a version of Scala that is not selectable in the edit menu, but is available as a [bleeding-edge release](http://www.scala-lang.org/download/).

The request is to have a way to flag the documentation area as requiring a new version number.

It is possible that there is a way to do this already; if so it is unclear in the UX, and the request is to make it more readily obvious/available. (I think I have enough reputation to see most things.)

Note, this is not about the fact that this particular topic is clearly misfiled.